# Demanding multiple coordinates from an undefined amount of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

Firstly I would like to give you an example, of what exactly I am talking about, and afterwards what I found out/different problems.

I would like to ask for every element, here points (they do share a class) with a diameter of 1 px. To simplify it, I thought of putting it inside an array. The amount of these points is undefined, there may be 2 or 100.
Afterwards i would like to store the x and y coordinates, which I get with the getBoundingClientRect() function, inside a new array. In which I would use every first for x and every second for y.
Now do not confuse this with the position within the array, I would like to know how I can "convert" the element from a query so I can use the getBoundingClientRect() function.

I hope this is all the information needed. I myself researched on here, but I could not find anything that was near my (rather big) demand.

I do not have any code, which I think would be useful.

Comment: "I do not have any code, which I think would be useful."  Yes. Even a non-working attempt would clarify the question.

Comment: The non-working attempt is made out of two lines. I understand it would be helpful if it contained more code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself. It is definitely not the smoothest nor the fastest solution, but it works.

```
            for(iAllPoints=0;iAllPoints<(aPoints-1);iAllPoints++)
        {
            //Creating necesarry variables and asking for the needed data from CSS
            var sPointPos = document.querySelector(".startPoint").getBoundingClientRect();
            var tarPoints = document.querySelector(".target");
            var AOfTarPoints = document.getElementsByClassName("target").length;
            var calculatedDistances = [];
            //Demanding all coordinates from each target point. Aswel as calculating the distance
            if (iAllPoints!=(aPoints-2))
            {
                for(i = 0;i<AOfTarPoints;i++)
                {
                    tarPoints = document.querySelector(".target");
                    //Calculating
                    var SideA = sPointPos.top - tarPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    var SideB = sPointPos.left - tarPoints.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    var CEPDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(SideA,2)+Math.pow(SideB,2));
                    calculatedDistances[i] = CEPDistance;
                    tarPoints.classList.add("inCalculation");
                    tarPoints.classList.remove("target");
                }
                minimum = Math.min.apply(Math,calculatedDistances);
                var smallestDistance = document.querySelector(".inCalculation");
                document.querySelector(".startPoint").classList.add("used");
                document.querySelector(".startPoint").classList.remove("startPoint");
                smallestDistance.classList.add("startPoint");
                smallestDistance.classList.remove("inCalculation");
                //Reseting the left unused points for next point
                document.querySelector(".inCalculation").classList.add("target");
                document.querySelector(".inCalculation").classList.remove("inCalculation");
                finalDistance += minimum;
            }
            else
            {
                for(i = 0;i<AOfTarPoints;i++)
                {
                    tarPoints = document.querySelector(".target");
                    //Calculating
                    var SideA = sPointPos.top - tarPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    var SideB = sPointPos.left - tarPoints.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    var CEPDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(SideA,2)+Math.pow(SideB,2));
                    calculatedDistances[i] = CEPDistance;
                    tarPoints.classList.add("inCalculation");
                    tarPoints.classList.remove("target");
                }
                minimum = Math.min.apply(Math,calculatedDistances);
                var smallestDistance = document.querySelector(".inCalculation");
                document.querySelector(".startPoint").classList.add("used");
                document.querySelector(".startPoint").classList.remove("startPoint");
                smallestDistance.classList.add("used");
                smallestDistance.classList.remove("inCalculation");
                finalDistance += minimum;
            }
```

I haven't given every single Variable, but you should be able to understand it either way.